# Radon Transformation

Tags: image-processing, integral-geometry

I have been tinkering over the line segmentation of images. I found that it is very well implemented in matlab with the Hough algorithm.

Now the Hough-transformation is just a special form of the Radon Transformation. 
I was now wondering how can detect the end points of a line in the image. 
The peaks in the of the Radon transformation $Rf(\theta, s) $ correspond to lines but how do I know where the endpoints are?

Kind Regards,

A. Dumas

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tommi.

All right folks it is easier then expected. Given an image with a line. the following image illustrates the Radon Space. (note the labelling is German )
[image]

The Maximum is the line without endpoints. The border of the big wave thing are the endpoints. More precisely if we know where the maximum is and we move 90 degrees on the x-axis to the border of the wave thing we get two other lines which are perpendicular to our line without endpoints. Then it is just a matter of finding the points of intersection and there you have it.

Well just a matter of old fashioned craftsmanship.